# iOS: request for up to date solution for UITabBarController rotation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitabbarcontroller, rotation

What is up to date best solution for rotating inner views when dealing with UITabBarController? I'm playing around with a standard app view hierarchy: In my main app delegate file, I'm creating UITabBarController, then, I'm creating UINavigationController, filling it with a UITableViewController (with instantiated custom subclass), and adding that UINavigationController to the first tab bar item. Now, I need UITableViewController to autorotate. I know that I need to implement shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation in all view controllers, therefore, I implemented it in my custom UITableViewController subclass implementation file:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
  // Return YES for supported orientations
  return YES; 
}
```

But the UITableViewController is not rotating :( .Now, I understand that there are UINavigationController and UITabBarController objects, that are sitting above my TVC but those two are instantiated directly not through a subclass, so there is no place where to return yes for autorotation. However, I'm able to solve this problem by subclassing a UITabBarController and implementing shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method in its implementation file. But I have read, that this is a non-recommended approach and my conscience feels bad :) Another working solution is to implement a category for UITabBarController (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269704/uitabbarcontroller-morenavigationcontroller-and-the-holy-grail-of-device-rotatio)...

So, these two solutions are the only ones that I was able to apply. Are there any other "out of the box" solutions, for example, setting some property on the UITabBarController or smth?

Answer (score 0):

In the class which you either subclass UITableViewController or implement UITableView in UIViewController, you need to set autoresizingMask for tableView. It is something like

`self.tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;`

and TableView should be ok and rotated properly.

Hope this help :)